# JavaFX blank site

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webengine

I want display the website "https://www.dazn.com/" in an JavaFX Webview, but all I get is a blank page.

In my little test applicatoin, every website (e.g. https://www.google.com or https://www.facebook.com) works. But "dazn.com" don't work.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");
    System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");

    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    final WebView webView = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
    webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setContent(webView);
    scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
    scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);

    webEngine.load("https://www.dazn.com");

    scene.setRoot(scrollPane);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setFullScreen(false);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Java Version:   1.8.0_112-ea-b04

JavaFX Version: 8.0.112-ea-b04

OS:             Windows 8.1, amd64

User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/602.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) JavaFX/8.0 Safari/602.1

Thank's a lot!

Comment: Your sample works for me on Ubuntu 16.04, Java version 1.8.0_101.

Comment: Does the background image loads for you?

Comment: No, all I see is a blank site. Ok thx, I will try on ubuntu too.

Comment: I tried on ubuntu 16.04 too, but I don't work. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove this line and the webpage loads.

```
    System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");
```

Comment: You only need to remove this one line actually look at edit. You can keep the other line. @FlorianD